# What does dup.sub! in Ruby, such as follows?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out what `s.dup.sub!` is doing in the following function. I assume `s` is a string. Sorry if this question is not appropriate.

```
def authenticated_url(s)
    s.dup.sub!(%r{^(https://)(.*)}, '\1' + access_token + '@\2')
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods are being run here:  [`dup`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-dup) and [`sub!`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-sub-21).

From inference, `s` is a string being passed in.  It's being copied subject to the rules of `dup` (which does not mutate the argument being passed in), then it is being mutated in place, embedding whatever value `access_token` holds between `https://` and whatever's after that.

As pointed out in the comments, a more straightforward approach would have been to use `s.sub` instead, since `sub` (without the `!`) will return a new string without the need to copy, and will at least guarantee that a string is brought back if no substitutions are made.

Comment: You might want to note that you `dup` the argument so that you don't affect the original, but it's very redundant. It would be better written as just `s.sub` to avoid overwriting the string.

Comment: @Entisburg:  Those are regex group numbers.  Note that `https://` is in group 1 and everything else is in group 2.  The `@` has no bearing on the regex; that's a character that's slated to appear before group 2.

Comment: Also `sub!` will return `nil` if no modifications were made. I'm willing to bet it is not the desired behaviour.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Or maybe that's precisely why this was done, and this is just really weird code. It's impossible to tell.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes: true that.